# Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS 5

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to iOS i am working on uitableview cell i had drag and drop the button to table view cell from objects inspector. but when i am making its IBoutlet it is showing an error like "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" what does it means?? we cant make outlets of UIbutton in tableview cell.kindly review it . i am stuck in it.i am making an outlet like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sa;
```

and the error is "The sa outlet to the UIbutton is invalid"

Comment: Are you working with storyBoard?

Comment: yeah i am working on storybaord

Comment: Check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios) it is for swift but answer will help you.

Comment: @Mishal, Then you are doing wrong thing. you need to give tag to that object. i will post answer regarding it.

Comment: hoow ??? will you please provide some help or update your answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your answer is that you use an object in UITableViewCell by reusing it,

So you can't create it's outlet except you create Your class for your "UITableViewCell".

Below is a reference for you,

I hope that it's useful for you.

You need to drag and drop the object in your `UITableViewCell`,
Then you have to give tag for that object.

then you can use it with its tag.

First give an identifier to `UITableViewCell`,

Below is a reference image for it.

[image]

Then give a tag to your UI object,
As this in this reference image.

[image]

Below is sample code for you which I use regularly,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    UITableViewCell *Cell = [self.TableListRegion dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"List"];

    UIButton *objectOfButton = (UIButton *)[CellLast viewWithTag:200];

    [objectOfButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YourSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return Cell;

}
```

Now you can receive that button event by,

```
-(IBACTION)YourSelector:(id)sender{
// Your Button in Cell is selected.
// Do your stuff.

}
```

Feel free to ask if you need more help regarding it.

Comment: but this is for label i want button ??

Comment: You can do same thing for button. What is your difficulty?

Comment: Use this,   UIButton *MapLegendSel = (UIButton *)[CellLast viewWithTag:8];
            
            [MapLegendSel addTarget:self action:@selector(enterinImprint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65671/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-sharma-vishal).

Answer (score 7):

You can create subclass for UITableViewCell like below code

Create new class named CCell.h and CCell.m

in **CCell.h**

```
@interface CCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *lblTemp;
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIButton *btnTemp;
@end
```

Now in your **Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import "CCell.h"

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CCell *cell = (CCell *)[tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CCell"];
    cell.lblTemp.text = @"asd";

    cell.btnTemp.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTempClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    return cell;
}

-(void)btnTempClicked:(UIButton *)btnTemp
{ 
     NSLog(@"Button Clicked Index = %d",btnTemp.tag);   
}
```

Now open your Xib > tap on your UITableviewCell > open right side navigator > open 3rd tab named (Custom Class) > add Class = `CCell` > now open last tab you will get `lblTemp` bind option.

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @MishalAwan Its a good way to use subclass for UITableViewCell so you can get outlets and set tags and manage other things. like set tag to button like indexPath.row and in button selector method you can recognize which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a custom cell, you need to create a class for it. You will subclass UITableViewCell.

For example (using the property that you had in your question):

1. Create a new Objective-C Class. Set the subclass to: UITableViewCell
   Give it an appropriate name (i.e. cell)
2. In your cell.h file:

Create your property: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sa;

In the cell.m file:

```
@synthesize sa = _sa;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}

return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

3.In Interface Builder, go back to the row that you created. 
Click the "Show Identity Inspector".
Under "Custom Class", set that to your cell file.

4.Hold down the "Option" key and click the "cell.h" file. Then connect the button to the IBOutlet.

5.In your table view controller file:

import your cell.h file.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That's it!

Everything should work then. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the button is part of a cell, and there will (possibly) be multiple instances of that cell when the app runs.

Assume that you can make the connection, and there are 2 cells (and thus 2 buttons) when the app runs, Cocoa Touch can't decide which button will be referenced by that only outlet (neither can you).

You can subclass the `UITableViewCell`, ask the table view to use your subclass for its cells, and connect the button to the outlet **in the subclass**. In that case there will be multiple instances of the subclass, and each instance will map to one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need want to create custom tableView cell it is recommended to subclass `UITableViewcell` and add `UIButton` in that class. And in your tableview delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can create an object of subclassed tableviewCell for every cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in UITableviewcell cell's label's outlet connection in  UIViewController,it should changed to Create a CustomCell in Subclass of UITableviewcell,then done in outlet connection in this subclass that error cleared.

Comment: Please anyone help me to find an error,am using FMDB to store the data in UITableview..invalid number of section 0,am reffered that all links but still am having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

@Mishal Awan

If you really want to do that and your have a finite number of cells. U can :

1. Changing your `ViewController` to be a subclass of `UITableViewController`, then drage a `Table View Controller` file to your `StoryBoard`
2. Changing the content of `Table View` in your `StoryBoard` from `Dynamic Prototypes` to `Static Cells`
   [image: 1]]
3. Then you can add some views to your cell, for example some labels
   [image: 2]]
4. Connectting the `label` to your `ViewController` and continue the remaining work

If you want to create a reusable cell, forget what i have said above

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is:

Just take the view or NSLayoutConstraint reference outlets in the subclass of table view cell instead of table view controller and access using object of table view cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method or any other method.

Note: This is a repetitive object so you can't take reference in table view controller.