# Why Label Outlets cannot be connected to UITableViewCell Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype.I want to add the outlets to that class and connect them.

But xcode do not respond.

And i try to add the outlets of button in the next time,it works.

I want to display a picture,it is pity that i don't have enough reputations.

I don't understand why this happen.Can somebody help me,Plesae!!

Comment: `YourCustomTableViewCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` - is this being called in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method?

Comment: Yeah..u cannto use outlets for your case..u need to use tags(u can set the tag in storyboard itself).

Comment: You can not connect UITableViewCell as IBOutlet as cell is a repetitive view.

Comment: @VamshiKrishna,i just saw this question,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios it seem ok to do so.

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh but i create a new table view cell subclass,and button work,but label could not.

Comment: If you created new subclass for your cell and given as class of your prototypeCell then all views you add to the prototypeCell can connect as outlet to your custom subclass.

Comment: You can add a link to a screenshot to your question...

Comment: I assume so ,but i don't know where i did wrong.There is only two step of it.First,i change the class name of prototype cell.Second,i create a class of it.Then i do the drag@Yuvrajsinh

Comment: I really want to do that,but i don't have enough reaputaton @Wain

Comment: A link is just text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a xib file. Delete UIView and drag UITableviewcell.
2. Set your UITableviewcell class and a identifier for the cell
3. Drag the components on the cell and connect them with your class.
4. On the method `(void)viewDidLoad` of  your UITableViewController, set:

   [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:nameOfXibFile bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifierOfCell];
5. On the method `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, set:

   YourClassTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifierOfCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

   and set the values for the labels `cell.label.text = @"Your text".`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a subclass for Custom `UITableViewCell`. Than After you can connect Label outlets.

Check out this great tutorial for creating custom `UITableViewCell`.

[Custom UITableViewCell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Answer (score 0):

To insert referencing outlet by drag you need to do it between @interface and @end statements, like a property (it is actually a property).
You can add a button outlet just because buttons have an action outlets, which are methods.