# Having trouble transferring interface from UIViewController to Table View (Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content)

Tags: ios, swift, interface, storyboard

I have a piece of code that has been running fine in it's view controller. I wanted to clean it up, so I added in a table view so that it would be more clean. I just created cells in the table view and drag and dropped my label and buttons. However now I have the error of

```
Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content
```

which I know has been asked before, however I cannot get a specific answer on why this happens. Here is my view controller code where the labels are being connected. I know that there is the solution of making a subclass, but everything already works in the view controller so I was wondering if there was a more simple fix to this.

```
class CharViewController: UIViewController, BLEDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
etc etc etc
```

And where the only thing I did was drag and drop from my view onto a table view cell.

Comment: Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550519/swift-outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content

Answer (score 1):

Protoype cells are repeating so it will not work. You have two options:

1) Use Static Cells.  These require a UITableViewController but they are not considered repeating content (static).

2) Create a custom UITableViewCell and connect the outlet there. You will then have to dequeue to cell as you custom tableView cell and adjust the label through that cell.

Comment: If I use static, will it work if the values can be changed anytime? For example a button that has a value of 1 can change values, and anytime the value is changed it sends data across to an external device. Will that still work?

Comment: The static cell should work just like the ViewController option. It will just be a single instance of that label and/or button.  If you are using the tableView strictly for formatting purposes it should work as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you may be trying to make outlet of objects that you have placed inside the cell prototype in you Storyboard.
To get rid of this error in future do the following steps

- **Step # 1**
  Create an other class that is subclass of `UITableViewCell`, select your cell from the view hierarchy and assign this class to the cell from this option just like you assign a New ViewController class to a ViewController in Storyboard.
- **Step # 2**
  Make your IBOutlets in your custom cell class just like you were trying to create that outlet in your UIViewController and/or in any other class.
- **Step # 3**
  For Example you have created two `IBOutlets` named `cellLabel` and `cellImageView`
  now you can access these properties by simply type casting your cell object while dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier method like this.

  ```
  let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"YourCellIdentifier", for:indexPath) as! YourCustomCellClassName;
  cell.cellLabel.text = "Any Thing";
  cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyImage.jpg");
  ```

Here is the image link that will show you how to Assign your class to your custom cell prototype. [image: Image Is Here]

Comment: I see I have a subclass. However I have code that does all the transfer already in the view. How can I transfer to a subclass?

Comment: I have add a picture in my answer's end which will demonstrate how to connect your cell prototype to your custom class.

Comment: Awesome, and I can use that step 3 in my view controller class?

Comment: Yes that step three can be use in your ViewController class

Comment: i have two questions, one in that use of unresolved identifier indexpath gives error. Also, in my subclass, is it ok that i only have iboutlets within the class body and thats it?

Comment: that is perfect fine if you only have IBOutlets in your subclass.

Comment: Can you share the code of your TableViewDataSource and Delegate methods that you have implemented in your ViewController.m file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132327/discussion-between-timedwalnut-and-syed-qamar-abbas).