# UIWebView not being displayed in UITableViewCell - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

In the following code, `webTableViewCell` is  a subclass of UITableViewCell (which I've created to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios)) in which I've binded an IBOutlet of webview from a  prototype cell of a tableView in my `viewController` to this `webTableViewCell` class.

The URLs are loading whereas the webViews in the tableViewCell aren't. I think the problem is within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Can someone help me out?

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        webTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Cell"];

if(!cell)
cell = [[webTableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/%@",[myArrayOfLinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSLog(@"%@", url);


NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[cell.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

return cell;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by URLs are loading? Can you provide screenshots.

Comment: I mean the urls are being generated which I've verified by `NSLog(@"%@", url);` Which screenshots do you want?

Comment: Post your code for your custom cell class, and add screenshots of iOS simulator se we can have an idea of whats showing and whats not

Comment: I've done NOTHING in the custom cell class EXCEPT for binding an outlet of the webview in the interface section of .h file!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no need to make a custom cell class.

do the following:

1. Change your cell class back to `UITableViewCell` in the Storyboard and make its Reuse Identifier as "MyCell" (without spaces).
2. Drag a webview and put it in your prototype cell in the storyboard (I guess you have already done this part), **and assign it the tag value as 999**.
3. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, do the following:

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/%@",[myArrayOfLinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   UIWebView *webView = [cell viewWithTag:999];
   [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

   return cell;
   ```

run your app now and check. this should work.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working. I've even tried adding a simple UIView and then used the tag like you've said, but they are not being displayed!

Comment: Can you please send me a sample file with just a `UIView` added to a tableViewCell using tags?

Comment: Sorry can't send you file at the moment. The `cell` creation is correct in the answer.  There must be some issue with your tableView.

Is your `tableView` connected properly? Are you doing `[self.tableView reloadData]` ? Bro, post screenshots of your storyboard , `.h` and `.m` files !

Comment: You didn't tell me to do `[self.tableView reloadData]`?
I'll post them in a moment

Comment: we are not meant to spoonfeed you here! Somethings are obvious to do. Anyway reload your tableview in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: 1. I'm using a subclass of `UITableViewController`. So the `tableView` is connected properly.
2. I don't know why I've to do `[self.tableView reloadData]` !Anyway it didn't work out !
3. http://postimg.org/image/pc1d688gr and http://postimg.org/image/n672bq50b

Comment: 1. make sure your array has data. 2. call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your `veiwDidLoad`. 3. add this line `aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` before `return cell;` 4. Checkk your UI Constraints!

Comment: Here is a zip file of what i've done. http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/538107/sampleFile.zip
I've forgotten to tick `isInitialViewController` in the project. Please tick it and run the file

It would be very helpful if you can tell me what's wrong!

Comment: Can you please do that or no?