# How to change subview of uitableviewcell programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm working on app that allows user to share photo like instagram. User can post a photo with or without caption, so the caption could be empty and the photo still posted to their feed. My client want to remove the view when the caption is empty and I'm using uitableview cell with autolayout for the post. When I tried to connect the captionview height constraint to my viewcontroller it gives me an error it says that ***the constraint outlet can't be connected to repeated content***. So, I tried to do it inside my code , but it doesn't change anything.

```
let captionString = object["caption"] as? String
    let captionView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(111)

    if captionString == ""{

        captionView?.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, captionView!.frame.width, 0)

    }else{


        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel).text = captionString

    }
```

I put above code inside **tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell** and I'm giving constraint in every view inside uitableviewcell so if I can change the captionView height other view will automatically resizing. How can I change the height of the captionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related info here:

[Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios/26561726#26561726)

You can't set the frame, when you're using autolayout that's invalid and won't work properly.

Either have 2 different styles of cell and choose which one to dequeue based on data availability, or add constraints so that you can collapse the label height to zero.

Comment: So the only way to do this is by creating subclass for the cell? can you give any related link in how can I do it?

Comment: that's the way you should do it, your approach with tags can work, but it isn't a good solution

Comment: How can I do it with viewwithtag? why it isn't a good solution?

Comment: because the code will be a convoluted mess. take the first option and have 2 different cells, it's simpler and cleaner all round

Comment: yeah, my code is a mess this is my first project on ios and I'm fixing it now. I'll try to use the first solution. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can create outlet of height constraint and set the height 0

like as:

```
@IBOutlet var captionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
captionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```