# how to determine which cell's textfield was just edited in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

What property can I access to find out?

I was learning some swift from [this tutorial,](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/10/3/data-sources-and-delegates-uicollectionviewdatasource) and I decided to give myself some problems to do. One was that in the tutorial, to edit a name, there is a `UIAlert`. I want to get rid of that and instead, have `UITextField` in place of the UILabel, so the user could simply tap on a name, and edit it. I would use the `textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)` function to update the model, which is a dictionary of names and picture filenames.

I set the view controller as the `UITextFieldDelegate`, I put in the function, but now I'm stuck, because although the text was updated just fine in one of the cells, I don't know how to tell which cell it happened in.

Comment: I'm willing to entertain the idea of having a UILabel, with an IBOutlet to the view controller, that is replaced by a text field if it's tapped on... but i'm trying to know the simplest and most "proper" way to go about having the best UI for this little app.

Comment: The simplest way is to set a tag for your textField. Ex. ``_textField.tag = indexPath.row``

Comment: Dave in the future, edit your question instead of writing follow-up in a comment. @Allen's advice is perfect.

Comment: @Allen where in my code do i set that tag for the textField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you probably can consider to subclass a `UITextField` to refer a `Dictionary` item.

```
class DictionaryTextField: UITextField {
    var item: [String : AnyObject]?
}
```

Also create a subclass of UITableViewCell to hold above `DictionaryTextField` as an `IBOutlet` property.

```
class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: DictionaryTextField!
}
```

After finished above setting, an item `Dictionary` of datasource can be set in `func tableView(:, cellForRowAtIndexPath: )`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell

    cell.textField.delegate = self
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textField.item = item
    cell.textField.text = "TextField \(item["name"]!)"

    return cell
}
```

Later, in the `UITextFiedDelegate`, cast the `textField` as `DictionaryTextField`. Then the item can be retrieved directly.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    guard let textField = textField as? DictionaryTextField else {
        return
    }
    print("Did begin editing: \(textField.item)")
}
```

The revised codes can be downloaded again with this link: https://db.tt/8j9ENf7b

Comment: hm. Here's where I was running into trouble. I don't see how to make an outlet for the UITextField, because Xcode says outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. is there some other way to make it a property?

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios thanks everybody at stackoverflow :)

Comment: @DaveKliman Did you connect the outlet to a subclass of ``UITableViewCell``? I just created a sample project and you can get it from here: https://db.tt/8j9ENf7b Please notice on the class ``TextFieldTableViewCell``. There is a ``UITextField`` property in it.

Comment: yep. i connected it up... ah. i looked at your code... so you extended the controller with the textfield's functions. neat! i'm starting to like this language for its versatility..

Comment: actually i just realized your extension, in file scope was exactly the same functionality as my making the view controller a textfield delegate... we have the problem that you're assigning a tag which is the row (or item, in my case with a collection view) and if there are any changes then those tags will no longer be valid. if one picture is deleted, all the tags in the pictures after that would have to be changed. there must be a less messy way of getting the indexPath.item out of that text field... superviews?

Comment: @DaveKliman The answer and codes of link both are revised. Please take them for references.

Comment: Oh excellent! That looks better than the sketchy superview idea I used (which did work at least but probably isn't kosher)