# Label Text cannot connect IBOutlet in Table View

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, iboutlet

I put one label text in my Table View row. Then Ctrl dragging to the ViewController.swift but error occurs. 
How to solve this problem? My Xcode version is 7.3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4JuJ.png)

Comment: Read something about table view controllers in iOS. It doesn't make any senses to connect a label in a cell to a view controller.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to say. I put just label and dragging to connect. Then, error occurs "Illegal Configuration: The lbltest outlet from the ViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.
"

Comment: Exactly. Labels within table view cells need to be connected to outlets in subclasses of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios)

Answer (score 1):

You must connect the **@IBOutlet into tableView cell** class not in the main class. first of all you must make the **custom class of tableview cell** and assign it on storyboard as suggested in picture and draw **@IBOutlet** on that **custom tableview cell class**. Please look the *attached image*.
[image: Image1]

[image: image2][image: image3][image: image4]

Hope it will help you.