# Wont let me connect an outlet to second view controller

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I am creating an app that has a second view after I press a button. So, I create the second viewcontroller.swift and try to control drag the button/textfield to the view controller class and it gives me this error:

> Illegal Configuration: The button outlet from the secondpage to the UITableViewCell is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Can someone please help me? Also please explain everything you do as I might not understand how to make something and where to put the code.

P.S. The second viewcontroller.swift file I made ends in A rather than M. If you need anymore information just ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios

Comment: See but I don't know how/where to (Create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype. Add the outlets to that class and connect them. Now when you configure the cell you can access the outlets.)

Comment: Give me more information about your setup - do you have a UITableViewController for the secondview? Are you trying to control drag the UITableViewCell? If so are you perhaps using the prototype cell?