# How/where do I create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype

Tags: swift

I have a second viewcontoller and was linked to this

> Create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype. Add the outlets to that class and connect them. Now when you configure the cell you can access the outlets.

But I do not understand where I put the subclass and how to make one.

> [Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios) The link I was sent to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, create the file**

The same way that you create a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`: In your project, go to New File. Select Cocoa Touch Class under iOS. The subclass is UITableViewCell and the name is whatever name you're giving it.

[image]

Within that class, you drag your buttons, labels, etc to create your outlets.

---

**Assign the class to the cell**

Remember to assign the class name to the cell in the identity inspector:

[image]

---

**Put it in code**

You will need a slight change in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
```

where "myCell" is the identifier you've given your cell in the storyboard, and obviously MyCustomCell is the new class you've created to which you are casting your cell.

Comment: Works! Thanks! But, another problem when I put a label in and ctrl drag and add constraints when I go to the app it isn't there. Also idk if this will help you but the view controller top setup(?) isn't in the right order. What I mean by that is that my first view has 1. ViewController 2. First Responder 3.  Exit         but my other one that the problem is with has it in 1. Exit 2. First Responder 3. View Controller

Comment: @Joe The label inside the cell doesn't appear?

Comment: Yes it does not appear. Also, I forgot to do

Comment: Also, I forgot to do >let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
where do I put that?

Comment: @Joe inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in your table view controller

Comment: I do not have cellForRowAtIndexPath. Do I just paste it in there? (Sorry for being difficult)

Comment: @Joe if you start typing it into your class, it will autocomplete the function and add it, then type your code inside. I think you may be well served finding a tutorial online for table view controllers and start from scratch so you can see what functions are implemented and how they interact.

Comment: What class do I put it into?

Comment: import UIKit

class page2Cell: UITableViewCell {
    override func cellForRowAtIndexPath{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("page2reuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! page2Cell
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backstrapLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
Like this? gives 2 errors

Comment: @Joe wrong class. Put it in the table view controller. Then go do some thorough reading on this whole process or you'll make yourself nuts doing it piecemeal and not understanding what goes where.

Comment: http://notes.io/eiMh Okay I put it in the other class but it still gives me the same errors as before. (check link for errors) This the right class BTW?class secondpage: UITableViewController {

Comment: @Joe This is basic stuff, sorry. Read up on it and post another question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: @joe Don't think that Shades is you computer instructor. You have to try and search yourself, not post here every problem you face.