# Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content in CollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When I am trying to connect a UILabel in a UICollectionViewCell that has been declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
```

It shows that:

> Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content.

I have done some search and find out that I need to use some kinds of connection of the outlet between UIView and the UICollectionView. But I do not understand what to do exactly. So how could I make such a connection so that UILabel in the UICollectionViewCell can be accessed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` which you should use in your collection view. The subclass is where you will add the outlet.

Comment: That helps. But could you provide more details on how to add an outlet into the subclass? I couldn't understand how to do that.

Comment: @ShunzheMa You will need to make sure that in the interface builder, you have the collection cell's class set to the new subclass you make. Then it's just like before -- `control-click-drag` and create the outlet (or whatever other method you are using to link the outlet.

Answer (score 0):

i too faced this issue, solution: `From viewcontroller kindly remove the IBoutlet of colllectionviewcell` . the issue mentions the invalid of your IBOutlet. so remove all subclass which has multi-outlet(invalids) and reconnect it.