# 'Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content' in subclass of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Xcode 9.2, Swift 4. For a cell in a Collection View Controller, I created a subclass named CollectionViewController. I linked the cell to this subclass. I created a Label in the cell on the Main.storyboard and linked it to the subclass like this :

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var personName: UILabel!
}
```

Then i try to access to this label in the collectionView function inside my CollectionViewController class, subclass of UICollectionViewController, which is linked to the Collection View Controller where my cell is :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.personName.text = "text"
    return cell
}
```

That's how i have this error : "The personName outlet from the UICollectionView to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

Comment: you mean runtime crash or compile error ???

Comment: Did u register a cell ?

Comment: The error in your title and the description in the rest of your question are inconsistent. The error in your title occurs in interface builder when you attempt to connect an object in a cell to an outlet in your view controller.

Comment: @yerpy - He's talking about IBOutlets, which means that he's talking about a cell on his storyboard scene. That means there's no registration necessary. You just set the base class for the cell in the storyboard.

Comment: @Rob Oh, Yes, you are right!

Comment: @Sh_Khan compile error

Comment: @Paulw11 apparently as explained Rob in his answer, i did that accidentally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you double check the "connections inspector" (the last tab on the panel on the right) for that control (and any other controls inside that cell). It sounds like something in the cell has a lingering outlet hooked up to the view controller. The connections inspector will help you identify that:

[image]

Make sure the view controller doesn't show up as one of the outlets. In the above example, I have "accidentally" created two outlets for this label, one to the cell subclass (which is correct) and one to the view controller (which is incorrect).

That will result in a compile-time error that says:

> error: The customLabel outlet from the ViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

If you delete the outlet connection between the cell and the view controller (or whatever non-cell class it's hooked up to), and this compile-time error will go away.

Note, the sentence before the "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" message will tell you precisely which outlet is causing the problem. You can even click on this error inside the "issues navigator" in the left panel and Xcode will jump to the storyboard and select the offending control (at which point you can directly open up the connections inspector) and find the offending outlet.

Comment: It was exactly that, thanks for your answer and the detailed explanation ! The sentence before the error was "The personName outlet from the UICollectionView to the UILabel is invalid". Didn't know i could click on it, nice tips, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Additional note for similar error condition:

In the error message I got, along with the message similar to above, Xcode(ver 12.0) also provided the `Object ID`, which I referred to in the `Identity Inspector tab` to eradicate the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

solution: From viewcontroller

> kindly remove the IBoutlet of colllectionviewcell

. the issue mentions the invalid of your IBOutlet. so remove all subclass which has multi-outlet(invalids) and reconnect it.

[The answer is already mentioned in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66009224/15074740)