# The outlet from the VC to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on a todo list app that works with a table view in Swift. The table view has a UILabel called `titleLabelOutlet`.  When I was building the app I got an error that says `The titleLabelOutlet outlet from the FirstViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.`I have never received this error before. How do I fix it? This is my code:

```
import UIKit

var phoneNumberList = [String]()
var titleFieldList = [String]()
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabelOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberLabelOutlet: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (phoneNumberList.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    phoneNumberLabelOutlet.text = phoneNumberList[indexPath.row]
    titleLabelOutlet.text = titleFieldList[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        phoneNumberList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        titleFieldList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Your outlets should be in cell class instead of viewcontroller because labels are inside cell
And in crllfor row at delegate you have to get your outlets like that
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellClass

cell.lbloutlet.text = "any text"
return cell

`

Answer (score 0):

Create **CustomTableCell** subclassing **UITableViewCell**.

Have Labels in cell and connect to *phoneNumberLabelOutlet* & *titleLabelOutlet* in CustomTableCell class.

use CustomTableCell in place UITableViewCell for cellForRowAtIndex function.
now you can set values for labels as

**cell.phoneNumberLabelOutlet.text  =  phoneNumberList[indexPath.row]
cell.titleLabelOutlet.text = titleFieldList[indexPath.row]**

Comment: when I do this in a UITableViewCell file it doesn't work