# The photoImageView outlet from the ViewController to the UIImageView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am adding the ImageView in Table View but I am getting the above error when I compile it? Do I need to add class for cell

[image]

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios

Comment: you need to give class of your call if you not create then create UItableviewcell class and give to tableview cell.

Answer (score 3):

**Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content**

You are getting this error message because you have given Outlet to cell's  imagevView in viewController's class.

You cannot give outlet directly.

You have to create Subclass of UITableviewCell and will be able to give outlet to any of cell's content.

or You can give Tag to specific view And access the view with tag when required.

Answer (score 1):

"Create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype. Add the outlets to that class and connect them. Now when you configure the cell you can access the outlets."
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios)