# Is it possible to have a UITableView under a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Long story short. I have a ViewController that has a ColletionView that's the main component of the page. The CollectionView has 2 reusable cell a Header and a Footer. I would like to have a TableView inside the footer but that's not possible I get the following error when I try to connect the TableView:

"Illegal Configuration: The tableView outlet from the ViewController to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

My tip is that I want to achieve this in a total wrong way.

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios

Comment: @richard I suggest you to take separate tableView and collectionView for better experience even you can achieve this in your way but It might be some tricky and difficult.

Comment: @ShivJaiswal I want to use this method because I want to have a dynamically growing CollectionView (item number) + I want to have a single scroll page.

Comment: @richardtulkan Oh..then I suggest you to use collectionView within tableView, it is bit easy compare to vice versa.

Comment: @richardtulkan - You should be able to use a "normal" `UIView`, with a table view as a subview, as the collection view footer view ***instead*** of a *reusable* view. Then it won't be repeating content, and you should be able to connect your table view properly.

Comment: @ShivJaiswal Thank you for your answer, I know it would be easier but then I would not be able to change the Header's height dynamically.(When I want to display more CollectionView Cell) :/ Any idea for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you did register the footer/header nib like this:

```
segmentCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: /* CellNibName */, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: /* CellId */)
```

and then dequeue the cell like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: /* CellId */, for: indexPath) as! /* Your Class */
    } 
    else {
    }
}
```

- so the trick is in your registered cell class as a footer you can go to the xib file and add the `UITableView` inside the reference /* Your Class */
- link the `UITableView in the cell class not the`UIViewController`class that contains the`UICollectionView`
- then pass the data you want when you dequeue the cell and perform all your business inside the cell class

Comment: Can't believe it but I solved it. Not exactly like you said it but because of you, thank you very much for your time and effort, I owe you. @karem_gohar

Comment: @richardtulkan you are welcome, just make sure when you got the knowledge to pass it on  to other people :-)

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

The solution was the following: I made a CollectionReusableView file for the Footer then exactly when @karem_gohar said I passed the following:

footer.tableView.delegate = footer.self
footer.tableView.dataSource = footer.self

I connected the tableView to the CollectionReusableView, I made an array to test it out I filled the tableView with the elements of the array.

Ps.:I made a TableViewCell and linked a label to it. The label showed the element of the array.