# How populate an image in table view from API?

Tags: xcode, api, uitableview, uiimageview, swift5

I am getting the error of “outlets cannot be connected to repeating content”. I am trying to have a table view where the image shows url images from an API. How do I do this?

Comment: You can't connect an outlet from your table view cells to the parent view controller. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios)

Comment: This is a very broad question but the matter of how to populate a table view from online / downloaded data has been handled here hundreds of times already so please search before asking.